# use a picture for the background in my blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to use a picture for the background of my blackberry app instead of the default white background. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
final Bitmap header_Bitmap = //your image
    VerticalFieldManager vfm_ = new VerticalFieldManager(
            Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR
                    | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL
                    | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x040811);
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, header_Bitmap.getWidth(),
                    header_Bitmap.getHeight(), header_Bitmap, 0, 0);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };
add(vfm_);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Background*, *BackgroundFactory* can be used to set the background of any *VerticalFieldManager*, *HorizontalFieldManager* or *MainScreen*. This support is available since JDE Version **4.6.0**.

Check the [API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/decor/BackgroundFactory.html).

```java
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("myBitmap.png");
Background background = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bitmap);
setBackground(background);
```